# Make topbar and header float

Tags: html, json

I have a theme where I can select to make the header float when scrolling down a page or the topbar float.
I want to make them both float, can you please tell me what to change?

Here is the code from the settings_schema.json file:

```
 {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Header Style"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "theme_float_style",
        "label": "Float style",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "label": "Default"
          },
          {
            "value": "keep-topbar",
            "label": "Float Topbar"
          },
          {
            "value": "keep-header",
            "label": "Float Header"
          }
        ],
        "default": ""
      },
```

when you select the header to float, this is what appears in settings_data.json:

```
"theme_float_style": "keep-header",
```

css:

```
/* ---Header--- */
body{ 
    &.keep-header{
      .mini-bar{
        @include box-shadow(0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        #header_logo{
          padding:5px 0;
          img{
            width:449px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

body{
    &.keep-topbar{

    }
```

Comment: can you add css and html? maybe in form on a snippet? Just to give more of a full picture of what you are going for

Comment: hi, here is the css: /* ---Header--- */
body{ 
    &.keep-header{
      .mini-bar{
        @include box-shadow(0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        #header_logo{
          padding:5px 0;
          img{
           width:449px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

body{
    &.keep-topbar{
        
    }

Comment: What is this? Wordpress themes?

Comment: This is a shopify theme

Comment: Please change your tags. It's not an html, json question.